# Как пишутся сложные слова?

Tags: орфография, сложные-слова

Как пишется семи восьмилетние дети? Надо дефис или следует писать слитно, например, как веломотогонки?

Answer (score 2):

Семи-восьмилетние т.е. семи- или восьмилетние)Дефис.

Answer (score 2):

Встречаются две формы: (1) семи-восьмилетние дети, (2)семи-,восьмилетние дети.

Форма 1 лучше смотрится, но ее сложно обосновать. Сравнить: контр-адмирал - контр-адмиральский, но здесь другая схема образования (сл.сущ. - сл.прил.).

Форма 2  учитывает схему образования из словосочетания (семь-восемь лет), но она прецедентная, так как дефис перед запятой, а не союзом, да и смотрится она хуже.

Слитное написание не читается и под схему "газоэлектросварка" не подходит (там нет дефиса в исходном сочетании).

Поэтому лучше писать "семи-восьмилетние дети".

Comment: Через дефис пишется, если есть союз, это мне понятно, а если без союза? Все равно ставить дефис. Но ведь в словах, например, без и, газоэлектросварка, веломотогонки пишется слитно.

Answer (score 1):

Через дефис. По аналогии с

***двух-трёхлетний (2-3-летний)***

См. http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%E4%E2%F3%F5-%F2%F0%B8%F5%EB%E5%F2%ED%E8%E9&all=x

Comment: Спасибо, мне все понятно